# std::shared_ptr initialized with other shared_ptr data

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I'm using recently new C++11 features such as std::shared_ptr, because I am converting a C code into Classes and in this code there is an heavy usage of "old-fashioned" pointers.
I have one doubt: in a method of a class, where i use local shared_ptr, can i initialized them with the data of the passed reference to another smart_ptr and then modify the data?
Example:

```
void myFunction(std::shared_ptr<T> &my_reference)
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> my_local_ptr(my_reference.get());

    /* Doing stuff on local pointer, 
       which modifies the object kept by my_reference pointer */
}
```

Am I doing it wrong? Or do you think is better to modify directly the data in my_reference, without doing this redundant operation?

Regards

Mike

Comment: By doing what you're doing, you now have *two* separate shared pointers, with separate reference count, but both pointing to the same object. This is generally not a good idea. If you just do e.g. `std::shared_ptr<T> my_local_ptr = my_reference;` the right thing will happen "automatically".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is wrong (it's technically valid code, but probably not what you intended). When constructed like this, `my_local_ptr` will point to the same object as `my_reference`, but it will have its own reference count (initialised to 1). In standard terms, it will not "share ownership" with `my_reference`.

And once `my_local_ptr` goes out of scope, it will happily call the deleter - destroy the object pointed to, and making `my_reference` dangling. Then, when the last `shared_ptr` sharing ownership with `my_reference` gets destroyed, it will call its deleter, resulting in a double delete (unless the danglingness causes a crash before that).

If you need a local copy, of the `shared_ptr` passed in (what for, anyway?), definitely copy the whole `shared_ptr` (including ownership):

```
void myFunction(std::shared_ptr<T> &my_reference)
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> my_local_ptr(my_reference);

    /* Doing stuff on local pointer, 
       which modifies the object kept by my_reference pointer */
}
```

Comment: Yes I've just read also this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer

I wasn't sure about the sharing of ownership with pure assignment.